# Unable to identify a type of variable in a php class

Tags: php, class, types

I did this routine to display the values of a phpMailer instance (when trying to find a bug):

```
echo('<p>Mail:</p>');
foreach($mail as $var=>$val){
    if(gettype($var)=="string") echo('<li>'.$var.': '.$val.'</li>');
}
```

Where $mail is the instance. But I get this error code:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class SMTP could not be converted to string in /home/gustavo/public_html/clientes/mullermoreira/website_mail.php on line 111

The last property printed was SMTPKeepAlive:(nothing reported here).

I try using is_string instead of gettype but I got the same result. Is there a correct or better way to do it?

Comment: Most likely the PHPMailer object implements a __toString() method, which will return something whenver the object is used in a string context, but the SMTP sub-class DOESN'T, so it can't be converted to a string or used in a string context. `$var` is probably always  going to be a string, because you're iterating over the properties of the object, but $val can be pretty much anything, and you'er trying to use it in a string context, hence your error.

Comment: It's complaining about `$val`, not `$var`.

Comment: You should post your code, no only how you're trying to debug. PHPMailer has been thoroughly used for many years, I don't think there's a bug in there that hasn't been fixed.

Comment: What is `var_dump($mail)`?

Comment: To amplify what Marc and Barmar said, if you change `if (gettype($var)=="string"...` to `if (is_string($val)...` you will probably be fine.

Comment: Marc B: your comment is more like an answer... Barman: I'll try var_dump. In theory $val is not printed as was a failure with $var before.

Comment: Yes! var_dump do the job, not very friendly, but it works. However, there is still the point of failing when trying to identify the type of the property. We solve for this case, but in other cases the only thing I can think is a try statement, otherwise there will be a chance of crashing. Orestes: wasn't looking for phpMailer bugs, but bad information passed to instance.

Comment: Jerry: I did try with is_string, it doesn't works either, same crashing message.